# Rendering local JSON data into a Tabulator Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabulator

I'm attempting to implement local JSON data into a [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) table. I specifically want to display the `obj.File.Name` JSON element.

I can render the data into a regular table, but when I incorporate Tabulator the data doesn't render at all. I think the problem lies with the `Tabulator Section` that's listed in the `JS Snippet`, but I'm not 100% sure. I'm interested in using Tabulator because of the features it offers.

Unless I misread it, the Tabulator [docs on loading data](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#array-initial) seems to be less focused on local files and more on external URLs, which is why I've come to ask about it here.

I've included a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0dnrLmv/) that shows the HTML and the JS.

### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import JSONfile from '../../../public/JSONfile.json';
import { basename } from 'path';

var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');

var categories = '';
var tableRes = '';

export default class {
    constructor() {
        this.loadData();
        this.loadTableData();
    }

loadTableData() {
    let tableRes = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {

      return {
        // "FileName": obj.FileLeafRef,
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name
        }
      });

///// Tabulator Section /////

      let tableData = tableRes;

      let table = new Tabulator("#km-table-id", {
        data:tableData,
        columns:[
          {title:"", field:"&nbsp;"},
          {title:"All Templates", field:"Name"},
          {title:"My Favorites", field:"faves"}
        ],
        pagination:"local",
        paginationSize:100,
        placeholder:"No data available"
      });

      table.setData(tableData);

  } // ------------------ loadTableData


} // ------------- export default class
```

### JSON snippet:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          ...
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            ...
          },
          "Name": "Guide to Product IDs.docx"
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "Guide to Product IDs.docx",
        "ResourceType": {
          ...
          },
          "results": [
            {
              ...
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": [redacted]
      },
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because the data is not in the format that Tabulator is expecting.

Tabulator requires an array of row data objects, based on your column definitions it is looking for this:

```
[
    {Name:"steve", faves:"this, that, the other"},
    {Name:"bob", faves:"this, that, the other"},
]
```

Loading local data into the table is covered in the [Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#array)